# BJT β gain of current

Tags: circuit-analysis

When I approach basically at university just by paper. Don't talk about the datasheet. I really don't know β exactly means. Just I analyzed the circuit to get the relative of the Collector current and Based current by applying BE loop and CE loop. Is the beta now equal to that ratio?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any analysis, at all. And you say you don't exactly understand \$\beta\$, either. Still more, it would seem difficult to say much of anything useful to you without at least having *some* idea of what you do know about BJTs. I think you should write a little more.

Comment: Maybe we should talk about when you supply voltage to  B and C. I know this direction of the current but about magnitude. Just if you read the document you can accept that β is it and that is all about the knowledge you have. So how to get  β and why is the current into Collector higher so much than the current into Based.

Comment: I think, if you see this picture you can analyze by KVL of BE loop and CE loop to get the relationship of IB and IC. In my thinking, you just get the scale equal to β But no. You just default β is the current gain. And get it from the data sheet. I think if you analyze any circuit you get the relationship of IB and IC and you know the β about (..)

Answer (score 3):

> I analyzed the circuit to get the relative of the Collector current and Based current by applying BE loop and CE loop. Is the beta now equal to that ratio?

If the transistor is in its linear region (V<sub>CE</sub> > roughly 1 V), yes.

If the transistor is saturated (V<sub>CE</sub> << roughly 1 V), no.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix, however, Ic/Ib=HFE and ic/ib=hfe=beta.

Not the same. hfe is used in a linear region of the characteristics.